# I cannot migrating database using php artisan migrate command. I am trying this on my Mac, I can't figure out what's the issues

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

These are the images

[.env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD8JM.png)

[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFUrA.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxbxc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The database defined in the .env is named "users". However, there is no such table in your MySQL instance as seen in PHPMyAdmin.
Please read the error message carefully. It has been made quite obvious.
Create a new database "users" and then retry.

Comment: I made the users db but still it says.    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:685